# Expressão Regular, pegando números entre dois textos pré definidos

Tags: c#, regex

Estou precisando retirar `números` de uma `string`. A `string` segue um padrão:

```
http://www.meudominio.com/1789519-texto
```

O número sempre vai estar entre `/` e `-`

Já consegui chegar na seguinte formula:

[/\d+(?=-)](http://regexr.com/3bnee)

O problema é que a `/` vem junto, e eu não queria isso, sei que posso cortar ela facilmente da `string`, mas gostaria muito de saber como posso retira-la do resultado usando a expressão.

Comment: Em que linguagem?

Comment: c#, adicionei a tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A expressão regular está correta. Falta apenas agrupar o resultado desejado e selecioná-lo:

```
    var re = new Regex(@"/(\d+)(?=-)");
    var match = re.Match("http://www.meudominio.com/1789519-texto");
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);
```

`match.Groups[0]` é a expressão inteira encontrada. Os próximos índices são os grupos, separados individualmente.

[Fiz um Fiddle pra você](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jNzzJK).